# Creating code for Moving onto Next Row upon Clicking on Button on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of values in column B where B2 is selected automatically. I want to create a macro where upon clicking on Button1, the selection would move to cell B3; another click and B4 and so on and so forth each requiring a click on Button1 to move onto the next row down up until the current cell is empty.

Thanks much guys.. I'm still new to VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("b2").Select
    For Each cell In Range("b:b")
        If cell.Value = "" Then Exit For
        cell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry.. How can I create the macro with the above conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) <> vbNullString Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```